# docker swarm phpmyadmin can't login to mysql server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

So i have deploy my stack application and everything is working as expected. Three container replicas running. Now i access phpmyadmin and try to login to the mysql but i got the error:  mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

Both the phpmyadmin and mysql container are on the same network.

```html
version: "3.9"
service:
    db: 
        image: mysql
        #container_name: mysql_db
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        secrets:
          - mysql_root_password
          - mysql_database
          - mysql_user
          - mysql_password
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_root_password
          MYSQL_DATABASE_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_database
          MYSQL_USER_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_user
          MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_password
        ports:
          - "9906:3306"
     
        networks:
          - back-tier

        volumes:
          - alpine-db_backup:/var/lib/mysql
          - alpine-mysql_logs:/var/log/mysql
          - alpine-mysql_cnf:/etc/mysql
        deploy:
          replicas: 3
          placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
          resources:
        reservations:
          memory: 128M
        limits:
          memory: 256M
          restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 30s
        max_attempts: 10
        window: 60s
          update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
        max_failure_ratio: 0.3
        
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        #container_name: phpmyadmin
        ports:
          - 8080:80
        environment:
          PMA_HOST: db
          PMA_PORT: 3306 
          PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
        depends_on:
        - db
        
        networks:
        - back-tier
        - front-tier
        deploy:
          replicas: 2
          resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 50M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 20M
          restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 30s
        max_attempts: 10
        
    networks:
        front-tier:
          driver: overlay
         
        back-tier:
          driver: overlay
```

Comment: After digging around for a few hours, i field that this is definitely a  DNS problem on swarm mode.

Answer (score 0):

For containers on the same network, to get another service's name resolved, you should use its name without the stack name as prefix. So, your `PMA_HOST` should be `db`, not `titanfxbmp_db`.

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  db: 
    image: mysql
    ...
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    ...
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3306
```